# Firefox won't write to SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: firefox, firefox-nightly

When the environment variable `SSLKEYLOGFILE` is set, Chrome and Firefox are supposed to log ssl information to that file to assist with debugging. After some experimentation, I got it to work in Chrome, but no matter what I do, Firefox won't output anything to SSLKEYLOGFILE.

Note, I am using MacOS

The steps that worked for Chrome are

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE="/Users/temp/sslkeyfile"
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
```

However, if I run Firefox in the same way, nothing happens, no matter what I try. (I am using the official Firefox build `67.0.2`)

After some searching, I found [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1555067), which suggests that it is an open bug in Firefox which is fixed in Nightly. However, I tried Firefox Nightly (`69.0a1 (2019-06-13)`) with the same results. No matter what I do, Nightly won't write to the key log either. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The SSLKEYLOGFILE was originally disabled when the Mozilla team were debugging an NSS issue in Firefox 65. I had reported the bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1523840) originally. It was subsequently reenabled in Firefox 66. However, once again for Firefox 67 it had accidentally been disabled in release builds again. I once again reopened that original bugzilla ticket to report it. And they then opened up a new bugzilla task that you linked in your post. A recent commit has removed the conditional that should now prevent that bug from reoccurring in future releases. My guess, the SSLKEYLOGFILE env. variable will work again when Firefox 68 releases, and on some Nightly version very shortly.